# fetch the value of SystemRestore registery key's value- RPSessionInterval

Tags: c#, registry

Is there any way to fetch the RPSessionInterval value of the registery key 
SystemRestore(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore)?

I just want to display the status of SystemRestore either enabled or disabled.

Language to be used is C#.

Comment: its not possible on a 64bit machine with this code.